# Trying to get "board" from "boards" use Pinia getter and receive undefined

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, vue-script-setup

what do i wrong?

I try to get the name of the board from Pinia Store.

1. I fetch the data from API onMounted in parent component (composition api setup):

```js
onMounted(() => {
  boardStore.fetchBoards();
});
```

and store the data in Pinia Store:

```js
 state: () => ({
    boards: [],
    activeBoardId: storage.getItem('activeBoardId') || null,
  }),
  actions: {
    async fetchBoards() {
      await apiClient
        .getBoards()
        .then((response) => {
          this.boards = response.data;

          return response;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return err.response.data;
        });
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getBoardById: (state) => {
      return (id) => state.boards.find((board) => board.id === id);
    },
    getActiveBoardId: (state) => {
      return state.activeBoardId;
    },
  },
```

2. In my component i try to get the name from the board via getBoardById():

```js
import { useBoardStore } from '@stores/boardStore';

const boardStore = useBoardStore();

let board = boardStore.getBoardById(boardStore.getActiveBoardId).name
```

I expect to get the name of the board from the Pinia Store, but receiving undefined.

i also tried to use computed:

```js
let board = computed(() => boardStore.getBoardById(boardStore.getActiveBoardId));
```

and can see the values:

```js
ComputedRefImpl {dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, __v_isReadonly: true, _dirty: true, _setter: ƒ, …}
...
value: Proxy
    [[Target]]: Object
        ...
        id:  95
        name: "Privat"
        ...
```

But when i tried to use access i get undefined:

```js
console.log(board)
console.log(board.name)
console.log(board.value)
console.log(board.value.name)
```

Also wehn i check Vue Dev Tools -> Pinia i see the "boards" Array with some items object. When i open one, i can see the "name":

```js
boards:Array[2]
  0:Object
    ...
    id:95
    name:"Privat"
    ...
   1:Object
    ...
    id:97
    name:"Work"
    ...
activeBoardId:97
```

I suspect that either I'm trying to access them incorrectly or they're doing it too early, that the data has not yet hit the store, because async.

It's probably a small thing, but i can not find the bug or fix :-)

```
I expect to get the name of the board from the Pinia Store, but receiving undefined.
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo here or a real issue in your code, but
`boardStore.getBoardById(boardStore.getActiveBoardId)?.name)`
has a closing brace that shouldn't be there at the end of the line.

Comment: Yes it's only typo here.

Comment: You could use the `const board = computed(() => boardStore.getBoardById(boardStore.getActiveBoardId));` and add `watchEffect` to see the value of the board when the data has been fetched to debug it:

`watchEffect(() => { console.log(board?.value?.name); });`

Or simply print {{ board?.value?.name }} in your template on the page. The computed property will update when fetched, so the printed name too.

Comment: Maybe this can help for answer my question:

    const boardStore = useBoardStore();
    const { activeBoardId } = storeToRefs(useBoardStore());
    const board = computed(() => boardStore.getBoardById(boardStore.getActiveBoardId));

Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihqyU.png

Comment: @cwillinx i receive the name of the board :-) in console.log (watchEffect), but why it's not work outside when i try to assign it to var?

Comment: You need the `.value` to get the “value” of the ComputedRefImpl. The result might be a proxy, in that case you could convert it with toRaw() (see https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw) like `toRaw(board?.value)?.name`— but I'm not sure if this is the case.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with "board" - it needs to happen in a reactive way.
- either you use it in the template with {{ board?.value?.name }}, or
- move the logic into the watchEffect function, or
- use the board in another computed value function,...

Comment: Nope, it still return undefined when i try it outside of watchEffect.

console.log(toRaw(board?.value)?.name); OR console.log(toRaw(board?.value));

ps. yes, i can use it in template, but not in the Script Setup =)

Comment: Outside watchEffect, in the setup part, the fetch function is likley not resolved yet, probably also not the `activeBoardId `, so `board` will contain some invalid value.

After the async code resolved, board contains a valid value.

Script setup code is executed before the promises are resolved.

Comment: The funny part, i get a value for activeBoadId, but i tthink its because i use const { activeBoardId } = storeToRefs(useBoardStore());

But how i can solve the Problem? I tried to move the fetchBoard to onMounted but it make no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe not the best one, but it's work:

```js
onMounted(async () => {
  await boardStore.fetchBoards();

  setBoardName();
});

watch(
  () => boardStore.activeBoardId,
  () => setBoardName()
);

const setBoardName = () => {
  const board = computed(() => boardStore.getBoardById(boardStore.activeBoardId));

  resetForm({
    values: {
      name: board.value.name,
    },
  });
};
```